# How to know if a coordinate is inside a polygon of coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

It turns out that I need to validate if a coordinate is inside a polygon, and if the coordinate is inside the polygon, it returns a column with the attribute 'SCANOMBRE', which contains the name of each polygon, already explaining the problem now I have the following data in a geojson file where the polygons are.

[dataset of poligonos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JdvDP3ZewIVDTS0sH8EHVe3Lx35Msg2l/view?usp=sharing)

this dataset contains the following columns

```
barrios = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('dataset/scat_geojson.geojson')
print(barrios.SCANOMBRE, barrios.geometry)
```

the above data is what interests me punctually

[image]

and now I have a file with coordinate points that I need to validate if it belongs to a polygon from the list above.

[dataset off points](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CqdQRsucLHkL6Ix_ooz_VCAGtdrejvsK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106648236381307366808&rtpof=true&sd=true)

This dataset contains in the Latitude and Longitude column

```
pdv = pd.read_excel('dataset/Matriz_Final.xlsx')
pdv.columns = pdv.columns.str.strip()
print(pdv.Latitud, pdv.Longitud)
```

[image]

Now comes my question, how do I know if each of these coordinate points is inside a polygon, and how does it return a dictionary with the coordinates and the SNAME variable, something similar to the following example.

[image]

With the validation that is carried out, I want you to give me the information in this way so that I can later graph it, I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data/code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - images aren't searchable, they can't be read by screen readers and assistive devices, and we can't use them to copy/paste when trying to help!
 Instead, print the dataframe and paste it in as a code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- have used countries as polygons / multipolygons (**barrios**)
- have generated some points, some will fall within countries (**puntos**)
- simple case of *left* `sjoin()` tells you which points are in a polygon and which are not
- have visualised to demonstrate it works (green valid points, purple invalid)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

barrios = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# generate some points, some are valid some invalid
puntos = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Latitud": np.linspace(*barrios.total_bounds[[0, 2]], 100),
        "Longitud": np.linspace(*barrios.total_bounds[[1, 3]], 100),
    }
)

# find valid points by do an sjoin
valid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(puntos,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(puntos["Latitud"], puntos["Longitud"]), crs="epsg:4326"
).sjoin(barrios.loc[:, ["geometry"]], how="left").assign(
    valid=lambda d: (~d["index_right"].isna()).astype(int)
)
```

#### sample output

|  | Latitud | Longitud | geometry | index_right | valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -180 | -90 | POINT (-180 -90) | nan | 0 |
| 1 | -176.364 | -88.246 | POINT (-176.3636363636364 -88.24600878787879) | 159 | 1 |
| 2 | -172.727 | -86.492 | POINT (-172.7272727272727 -86.49201757575757) | 159 | 1 |
| 3 | -169.091 | -84.738 | POINT (-169.0909090909091 -84.73802636363637) | 159 | 1 |
| 4 | -165.455 | -82.984 | POINT (-165.4545454545454 -82.98403515151516) | nan | 0 |
| 5 | -161.818 | -81.23 | POINT (-161.8181818181818 -81.23004393939394) | nan | 0 |
| 6 | -158.182 | -79.4761 | POINT (-158.1818181818182 -79.47605272727273) | nan | 0 |
| 7 | -154.545 | -77.7221 | POINT (-154.5454545454545 -77.72206151515152) | 159 | 1 |
| 8 | -150.909 | -75.9681 | POINT (-150.9090909090909 -75.9680703030303) | nan | 0 |
| 9 | -147.273 | -74.2141 | POINT (-147.2727272727273 -74.2140790909091) | nan | 0 |

#### visualize validation

```
m = barrios.explore()
valid.explore(m=m, column="valid")
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but as I mentioned I am new, it turns out that I am getting an error and I have searched and I cannot find the solution, the error says like this:

Comment: ImportError: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`. See installation instructions at https://geopandas.org/install.html

Comment: `pip install rtree` - spatial joins depend on optional package. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#dependencies

Comment: How can I make it so that when I do this validation, it not only returns me if it is 1 or 0, but also other fields of the dataframe, the geojson has the polygons named by sectors, so I need to know which sector each point belongs to.

Comment: you have **ijndex_right** so you can use pandas merge/join to pick additional columns from. RHS data frame

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, how would it be? Do you have any example?

Comment: improve your question with usable sample data and expected outcome (do not use images). you mention two data frames **barros** and **puntos** where I have had to try to imply contents as it's not stated or provided in question in usable way...  function I refer to: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Comment: Hi, I get the error: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'sjoin'

Comment: from geopandas.tools import sjoin

Comment: gpd.sjoint(point, poly, ...)

Comment: @pyaj you need to have geopandas 0.10.0 to use `sjoin()`

Comment: Alright I have version 0.9.0 of geopandas and used the code above. Thanks